# Heston Model and antithetic variables

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

I was implementing some variance reduction techniques for the heston model and came up with a question when implementing the antithetic variable technique. Namely, I was not sure if I had to implement it into the stochastic process (discretized process with the Euler scheme for the underlying and the volatility process) for the underlying and also for the volatility or would it be enough just to implement it in the stock price process?

Comment: If you are trying to obtain the benefits from applying antithetic variables, the "normal" thing would be to do it for both, stock and volatility processes. I can't see any good reason to do it only for the underlying stock price.